# Article suggestion for Russian reading

Tags: reference-request, mathematical-russian

I apologize if this question does not really fit here.

I appreciate if someone can suggest math research articles in Russian (to practice reading, learning some math related terminologies etc.)

I don't want to restrict any subject or level of difficulty, but I prefer an original work which will be interesting to read. Many thanks.

Comment: Very cool. I have no doubt your question will be deleted by the gods, but, for the nonce: admirable!

Comment: Why not try to access web sites of the math departments of Russian universities?

Comment: @.Aruralreader Thanks! @user2661923 I expect they will publish recent papers, which I doubt I can differentiate what might be nice to read. But I will try in a moment to see if I can.

Comment: I read Matiyasevich's paper on his theorem of recursive equations being diophantine, about three or four years ago. The link is [here](http://www.mathnet.ru/links/4b3d7416d468f851435904dae4c97a94/znsl2072.pdf). I learned some Russian for it (took a few months), and loved reading the paper. My mother tongue is nowhere close to Russian , although I still managed to astonishingly find that some words matched very well! From there I also picked up Balkan languages. Papers in Balkan languages often contain brilliant inequalities and mind boggling elementary arguments on simple topics!

Answer (score 3):

Try Успехи математических наук
(which is translated in English as Russian Mathematical Surveys).

http://www.mathnet.ru/php/journal.phtml?jrnid=rm&option_lang=rus

and in particular their archive, where you get free access to articles three years old or older:
http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?jrnid=rm&wshow=contents&option_lang=rus

It publishes research on various math areas, and as to picking work interesting to read, you are on your own, browse the archive, titles and abstracts.

I have occasionally read math papers in Russian in the past (learned Russian in school in Bulgaria years ago). In particular some interesting ones to me in the area of general topology, a very old Memoir (from the 1920's) by Alexandroff and Urysohn, a more recent 1970's paper by Mischenko about Linerly Lindelof spaces (finally compact, forgot the entire term, in Russian). In general, at least for older papers, but also new ones, some of the terminology is different, e.g. bicompact (instead of compact), finally compact (instead of Lindelof), and I don't know much about other areas. I am pretty sure you could find more journals like that, but this was the first one for me to think about (I may look for more later).

Well, actually here is another well-known one,
Математические заметки (Mathematical Notes):
http://www.mathnet.ru/php/journal.phtml?jrnid=mzm&option_lang=russian
and its archive
http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?jrnid=mzm&wshow=contents&option_lang=rus

And (on the same general website) they have a list of other journals.
http://www.mathnet.ru/ej.phtml?option_lang=eng
or (in Russian)
http://www.mathnet.ru/ej.phtml?option_lang=russian

Good luck!

Comment: (+1) I can't read Russian at all, but I'm very familiar with Russian Mathematical Surveys (I've flipped through all volumes from 1960s to mid 1990s on several occasions during the 1990s, photocopying many, many papers dealing with cluster sets, descriptive set theory, seemingly interesting but out-of-the-way topics in general topology and approximation theory and several other topics, biographies and bibliographies of various Russian mathematicians (often these are multi-authored x0'th birthday celebration pieces), historical and survey papers, etc. **(continued)**

Comment: @Jo': Thus, I strongly recommend [the corresponding original Russian publication](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?jrnid=rm&wshow=contents&option_lang=eng).

Answer (score 2):

A nice bite-sized place to start would be the Международная Математическая Oлимпиада: https://www.imo-official.org/?language=ru.

Click on задачи, then for most recent years you can download the problems in the language of your choice. Удачи!

---

Update: for articles, consider the publication Квант. It was a popular science magazine aimed at school students and teachers, and its archives are freely available. Here's the collection of its mathematics articles: http://kvant.mccme.ru/rub/19A.htm

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I checked it but I am more interested in an article.

Comment: @Jo' Please see the update.

Comment: I just found some time to check the link, and some of them looks interesting, thank you. I am still going to leave the question open, as I am looking for a research article, which is not that really clear in my question.